# How to find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}^*$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I already know that if m and n are coprime, then $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m^* \times \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Now, Is it possible to describe specifically all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}^*$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, respectively?

I have tried to find such a subgroup using the isomorphism between two groups. (the image of a group is isomorphic to the group if the map is injective) But, I think the image may be impossible to describe specifically.

Do you have any ideas? I need your help. ;(

Comment: This is not very easy. For example, if $m=35$, $n= 171$, then the two unit groups are $C_2 \times C_4 \times C_3$ and $C_2^2 \times C_3 \times C_9$, and there are lots and lots of subgroups isomorphic to these in their direct product. Why would you want to find all such subgroups anyway?

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to formulize it. Then, is it possible to describe subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}^*$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, respectively? Clearly $\mathbb{Z}_m^*\times\{1\}$ is a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$. But I have no idea whether the subgroup can be expressed specifically by the element of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}^*$.

Comment: $\{ \lambda m + 1 : 0 \le \lambda < n, \gcd(\lambda m + 1,n) =1 \}$ is a subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}_{mn}^*$ that is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}_n^*$. This is just the image of ${\mathbb Z}_{n}^*$ under the natural ring isomorphism. For example, for $m=3$, $n=5$, it is $\{1,4,7,13\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was done like you, but I want to see more specifically. However, I realize it is enough. Thanks!